# Leetcode Merge In Between Linked Lists

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

The question I am trying to solve is worded as follows:

> You are given two linked lists: list1 and list2 of sizes n and m respectively.
> Remove list1's nodes from the ath node to the bth node, and put list2 in their place.

I have written my solution as:

```html
    def mergeInBetween(self, list1: ListNode, a: int, b: int, list2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        count = 1
        curr = list1
        while count < a:
            curr = curr.next
            count += 1
        curr2 = curr
        while count < b:
            curr2 = curr.next
            count += 1
        curr.next = list2
        curr3 = list2
        while curr3.next:
            curr3 = curr3.next
        curr3.next = curr2
        return list1
```

I am struggling to understand why it does not work. I cannot seem to find my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two small mistakes:

1. Replace `curr2 = curr.next` with `curr2 = curr2.next`. I believe this is just a typo in your part.
2. `while count < b` should be `while count <= b + 1`. This is because we want to remove all nodes from `a` to `b`, *including* both `a` and `b`.

```html
def mergeInBetween(self, list1: ListNode, a: int, b: int, list2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        count = 1
        curr = list1
        while count < a:
            curr = curr.next
            count += 1
        curr2 = curr
        while count <= b + 1:
            curr2 = curr2.next
            count += 1
        curr.next = list2
        curr3 = list2
        while curr3.next:
            curr3 = curr3.next
        curr3.next = curr2
        return list1
```